# A Facebook search query that returns only one result

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Does someone have an example for such a query? I need a query for the https://graph.facebook.com/search address and not for a specific user. I want to see the response I get, especially if Facebook still encompasses it with a data element even if there's only one result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I am understanding you question correctly, but you can limit the amount of results you get using LIMIT:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=facebook&type=application&limit=1

Comment: You were right, I was able to get 1 result with a different query using your suggestion. Maybe your specific query returned 0 results (strange however, because there is a Facebook application), but the idea was good, thanks.